# average number of file lines from CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'd like to compute the average number of lines of specific files from CMD.
To find the number of lines of one file I've got:

`findstr /R /N "^" "FILENAME" | find /C ":"`

So I'd have something like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set sum = 0
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    set tmpnum = findstr /R /N "^" "file-%%x.csv" | find /C ":"
    set /a sum=sum+tmpnum
)
echo %sum%/10
endlocal
```

The problem is that `sum` is always 0 and I believe `tmpnum` does not get the correct value assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set tmpnum =` line is wrong, you cannot set a variable to the output of a command like that. The correct syntax is

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    for /f %%c in ('findstr /R /N "^" "file-%%x.csv" ^| find /C ":"') do (
        set /a sum=sum+%%c
    )
)
```

Of course the `echo %sum%/10` will also not do the math -- you need another `SET /A` for that.